# Microsoft Bot Framework - Facebook authentication, account linking

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, botframework

I want to authorize user through bot and get proper information from database while chatting.
User is registered to my website database using facebook account.

So far, I have this:

```
   var resultMessage = context.MakeMessage();
            resultMessage.Type = "message";
            resultMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
            List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
            List<CardAction> plButton = new List<CardAction>();
            plButton.Add(new CardAction
            {
                Value = "myurl/link",
                Type = "signin",
                Title = "LogIn"
            });



            SigninCard plCard = new SigninCard("You need to authorize me", plButton);
            Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
            resultMessage.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
```

On the other side, where I should authorize the user, I have this:

```
public Uri link(string resource, string clientId, Uri redirectUri, User userId, string extraQueryParameters)
{

  return redirectUri;
}
```

But that's not correct.

- What parameters should I send?
- How to handle this?
- How to redirect user on Facebook Messenger, again?
- How to authenticate and get (stored) userdata from my database into bot ?

Thank you in advance for your replies!

Comment: do you want to authenticate against Facebook or against what?

Comment: I added additional question. Should be clear now.

Comment: So you want to authenticate the user against your DB? How would you know who the user is then? Do you have an identity provider? Do you use oAuth? It's still not clear....

Comment: I want to check if user exists in my db. If exists, then, get proper data into bot. Something like that.

Comment: And what's the issue that you are having there? What have you tried? It's seems like a simple call to a DB based on what you are explaining..

Comment: What parameters to use ? In the database is stored app_scope_user_id, first name, last name. 
Bot gives page_scope_id. Can't make query so simple ...

Comment: I figured this out. I made oauth2 authentication and now works everything properly.